# How to dynamicly generate input fields in a list, then retrieve text from said fields?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am populating a list of input fields to allow a user to input numerous locations. (I have found a way to populate the list, but I think its probably not the proper way and since I'm just starting, I figure I better learn to do it right). I populate the list like this:

```
function addLocationBox(){
    $('#InputBoxesList').append('<li><input type="text" /><input type="button" value ="Add Location"  onclick="addLocationBox();"/></li>')
}
```

When the user has filled out the fields, and pressed a submit button later on in the page, I need to know how to retrieve the text they have inputted. Any suggestions? I am brand new to javascript, so any additional pointers are also welcome :).

Comment: Just select `$("#InputBoxesList input")` and loop over them to get the text of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to loop between input.

Let's say you want to `POST` your input values with Ajax and JQuery. Only input, not textareas or selects, it's easier for the exemple.

First, you need your text inputs and a string variable to store the data. 
In this string, I often store first the `value` of my submit. It's useful server-side.

```
var $inputs    = $("input").not("input[type=submit]"),
    submitval  = $("input[type=submit]").val(),
    datastring = "submit="+submitval;
```

Then you use `.each()` to loop your input and append names/values in the datastring :

```
$inputs.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      name  = $this.attr("name"),
      val   = $this.val();

      datastring += "&"+name+"="+val;    
});
```

You now have a datastring you can POST like this, per exemple to a form.php :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: datastring,
  url: "form.php",
  success: function(data) {
    // your success handler
  }, 
  error: function() {
    // your error handler
  }   
});
```

It's not a cut and paste solution, more a general way to do it.

It won't handle textareas, checkboxes, selects, etc.
It won't handle multiple forms.
It won't check the data before posting it.

So use with caution.